# Move background - Cocos2D

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to develop a car game in which opponents are coming from opposite direction. And we have to avoid collision. For this I want to move my background as the opponent cars approach the good car. What should I do to move the background?

Regards,
Stone

Comment: change it's position ? Use actions or move it manually

Comment: What if I have used more than one layer?

Comment: if you want to move them all together put them all on a parent layer and move the parent. You can use one of them as a parent by the way

Comment: Can you suggest me with some tutorial which elaborates this concept?

Comment: use CCnode addChild method. Then the child will be moved together with it's parent. There are some examples using this coming with cocos2d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.- You need to create a map: example with program "Tiled". 
2.- Add to resources 
3.- Insert code:

```
CCTMXTiledMap * tmxMap = [CCTMXTiledMap tiledMapWithGMXFile:@"Map.tmx"];
[tmxMap runAction:[CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:1.0 position:ccp(0,-400)];
```